# How to check that you have been login use session & curl?

Tags: php, session, curl

I need login to get token to run other api, I use curl to post. This is my code:

```
function login($email, $password){
        if (!isset($_SESSION["access_token"])){
                print("\nRUNNING LOGIN API SCRIPT...\n\n");
                $data  =  array('password'=> $password,
                                'scope'=>'tokencheck,90days@Access,memberinfo_read_pointsummary,memberinfo_read_name,90days@Refresh',
                                'client_secret'=>'****',
                                'client_id'=>'***',
                                'username'=> $email,
                                'grant_type'=>'password');

                $login = SendRequest('***', true, $data, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'), true);

                $token = json_decode( $login[1],true)['access_token'];
                $_SESSION["access_token"] = $token;
                print "\nEND LOGIN API SCRIPT!!!\n";
        }else{
                $token = $_SESSION["access_token"];
        }
        return $token;
}
```

Here is my setup cookies in SendRequest function:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/Users/***/Desktop/***/cookies.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/Users/***/Desktop/***/cookies.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 0);
```

But it not work, api alway call when I rerun script. What is my wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer was:

> The way you described it, it seems like your session is ALWAYS not
>   set. Remember to check whether or not you're running `session_start()`
>   before invoking your login function.
>
> The `$_SESSION` is not set if you don't start the session.

From the chat session with OP I understood he is actually running it from the command line, and that's why `$_SESSION` is not working.

`$_SESSION` is a superglobal filled by `session_start` native PHP function. When PHP receives a HTTP request through a webserver, it creates a local file under a hash name and store your session data in said file. Through the HTTP response, it sets a cookie with the hash name created. This is how PHP knows which session belongs to which user and how to recover data from previous executions (as in a web environment, a request is processed from begin to end and then responded).

Command line PHP has no access to $_SESSION 'cause it doesn't follow the same process flow a http request runs, it has no cookies and can't create them natively.

Maybe setting up a curl client with a cookie jar may work, but it would be an extra layer as this curl client would call "login.php" file in a webserver, and this file would call the login API.

Comment: Sorry, I don't say with you that I put session_start() at the first of script.

Comment: When you run your code, it always prints "END LOGIN API SCRIPT!!"? What if you try to output your session? Try using `var_dump($_SESSION);` right after printing the "end login" message and see what's in it.

Comment: Alright, try outputing your `$login` variable right after your SendRequest call. Perhaps it's null or anything like that and then it's failing to access it's index 1.

Comment: I want to say, var_dump($SESSION) alway return empty before if. when I return script. login have value and work fine.

Comment: Oh yeah, I understand `$_SESSION` is empty before `if`, but how is it set right after you set it? Are you sure you're maintaining your session cookie between calls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124304/discussion-between-melanef-and-phongvan).